Are there laws in philosophy, science, and everyday life that say simpler explanations are more likely?
I asked in a previous question about the laws of the universe. There are no laws in our universe that say simpler explanations are more likely.
Are there laws in philosophy, science, and everyday life that tell us that simpler explanations are more likely?
Are there laws in philosophy, science, and everyday life that tell us that explanations with fewer entities are more likely?
Are there laws in philosophy, science, and everyday life that tell us that explanations that have fewer types of entities are more likely?
Are there laws in philosophy, science, and everyday life that tell us that explanations that have fewer explanations are more likely?

See Occam's Razor.

I don't get 'more likely' but 'possible'. For example when the geocentric model of the solar system was replaced by the heliocentric model, the planets' orbital computation was vastly simplified. Neither was wrong: they had a different point of view. Who knows what a future shift in perspective may bring (to anything else). Just imagine the guys in Flatland making the profound realisation that the Earth is round!

"God said it, I believe it, and that settles it!" is a hell of a lot simpler than a textbook on quantum field theory. Simpler isn't always better.

@user4894 Better for who? Useful doesn't have to mean useful to science. In this case, it's useful to powermongers who want to maintain control over an uninformed populace. And it works. It's an explanation that completely eliminates having to think about anything, and ensures the "right sort of people" get and retain power. Extremely useful and beneficial to them.

There are no such laws in any field. There are "rules of thumb" or guiding principles which suggest that simpler explanations are usually preferable than more complex ones, but this comes from a combination of observation and probability, it's not some fundamental requirement.
Throughout history humans have found that simple explanations tend to be more useful than complex ones. This doesn't mean the simple explanations are the most accurate, or even that they are accurate at all. It just means that at the time they are referenced, they provide a useful model for explaining things. Sometimes that usefulness is what we would consider scientific, but often it's more societal, such as religious proscriptions, cultural taboos, etc.
Over time, as observations improve with better technology, old explanations fall away and newer ones take their place; not because the newer ones are simpler than the earlier ones, but because the older, simpler explanations are revealed to no longer actually explain things. The newer explanation may not be simpler than the previous one, but it's probably the simplest one that is still useful when the previous one is no longer.
If you have two possible explanations for a phenomenon, and one of those explanations involves a complicated combination of rare events taking place, while the other involves a single, less complex event, then from the perspective of probability, the simpler explanation is more likely to be true, because it is the one that's more likely to happen frequently enough for you to observe the phenomenon.
This doesn't mean the simpler explanation is correct, it just means it is sufficient to explain the circumstances, and without some specific reason to reject it, there's no reason to think a rarer, more complex explanation is more useful.
